# For-loop in tf.function returns Tensor("while/Placeholder:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)

Tags: python, tensorflow, for-loop

I want to use a for loop over a tensor in a tf.function, like this:

```
@tf.function
def test(x):
    for i in range(tf.shape(x)[0]):
        print(i)
```

I define:

```
S = tf.random.uniform([2,2],0,1)
```

Then

```
test(S)
```

gives

```
Tensor("while/Placeholder:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)
```

While

```
for i in range(tf.shape(S)[0]):
    print(i)
```

returns

```
0
1
```

Why can I not loop over the length of the tensor in a tf.function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`tf.print`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/print):

```
import tensorflow as tf

@tf.function
def test(x):
    for i in range(tf.shape(x)[0]):
        tf.print(i)

S = tf.random.uniform([2,2],0,1)
test(S)
# 0
# 1
```

Kindly check the side effects of using python operations in `tf.function` [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#executing_python_side_effects).